# Is it adharma for a daasi to be stripped by her swami?

Tags: mahabharata, dharma, duryodhana, draupadi

Yes, you got it right, in Star Plus Mahabharata, it's said by Duryodhana, that since Draupadi is now his [*daasi*](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/d%C4%81s%C4%AB/100781/1) ('female servant or slave') she has to accept his orders and he can strip her since he's her swami. Was he right? Or is it adharma?

Comment: Related question on the same topic: [Why did the Pandavas sit quiet when Draupadi was being disrobed by Dushasana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19899)

Comment: "she has to accept her order" - who is her?..also "is it adharma" or was it adharma

Comment: @YDS updated...

Comment: First, Star Plus Mahabarata is distorted version based on creative imagination of producers. They themselves mention it in Introduction. It is more like soap-opera serial, hence it is aptly nick-named as Mega-Bharat. Second, asking religious/scriptural questions based on brain-farts of commercial people is a waste of time.

Comment: @ram I want to second this. Best bet is to actually read the Mahabharata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current context, the word [dāsī](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/d%C4%81s%C4%AB/100781/1) means *female slave* not *maid servant* ([paricārikā](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=hk&q=paricArikA&lang=sans&action=Search)).

After losing all his brothers Yudhiṣṭhira bets himself and says, should he lose, he'll do anything the Kauravas ask him to:

> Sabhā Parva / Dyūta Parva - Chapter 58
>
> Shakuni said, "O Kounteya! You have lost a great deal of riches. You
>   have lost your brothers, your horses and your elephants. Tell us if
>   there are any riches that you have not yet lost."
>
> Yudhishthira replied, "I myself am left, especially loved by all my
>   brothers. **If won over, until the time of destruction, I will do
>   whatever deed I am asked to do.**"
>
> At these words, Shakuni resorted to deceit and told Yudhishthira, "I
>   have won."
>
> [*Debroy, Bibek. The Mahabharata: Volume 2 (pp. 222-225)*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XYN5YDK)

And later when they were asked by Karṇa to strip, the Pāṇḍavas do not hesitate:

> Sabhā Parva / Dyūta Parva - Chapter 61
>
> ...
>
> When the noise died down, **Radheya**, who was almost senseless with
>   anger, gripped his lustrous arms and **uttered these words**...
>
> > It has been ordained by the gods that a woman should only have one husband. However, she submits to many and it is therefore certain that
> >     she is a courtesan. It is my view that there is nothing surprising in
> >     her being brought into the sabha in a single garment, or even if she
> >     is naked. In accordance with dharma, Soubala has won all the riches
> >     the Pandavas possessed, including her and themselves. O Duhshasana!
> >     This Vikarna is only a child, though he speaks words of wisdom. **Strip
> >     away the garments from the Pandavas and Droupadi.**
>
> **On hearing these words, the Pandavas took off their upper garments and
>   sat down in the sabha.**
>
> *[Debroy, Bibek. The Mahabharata: Volume 2 (pp. 233-235)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XYN5YDK)*

So, why did Draupadī disobey the order? What are the rights of a wife and that of a dāsī (female slave)? Aren't wives the property of their husbands? If husband is a slave, doesn't wife automatically become a slave? Bhīṣma seems to agree:

> Sabhā Parva / Dyūta Parva - Chapter 60
>
> Bhishma said, "O fortunate one! Since the ways of dharma are subtle, I
>   cannot properly resolve the question you have posed. One without
>   property cannot stake the property of others. **But women are always the
>   property of their husbands.** Yudhishthira will abandon the entire earth
>   with its riches before he gives up truth. **The Pandava has himself said
>   he has been won.** Therefore, I cannot resolve this issue. Shakuni has
>   no equal in dice. Kunti's son has voluntarily played with him. The
>   great-souled one does not think he has resorted to deceit. Therefore,
>   I cannot answer the question."
>
> *[Debroy, Bibek. The Mahabharata: Volume 2 (p. 228-232)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XYN5YDK)*

If Draupadī is the property of Yudhiṣṭhira and his brothers, Yudhiṣṭhira staking her after losing himself is an illegal bet and shouldn't have been allowed in the first place. So the question whether Yudhiṣṭhira bet Draupadī *before* or *after* he lost himself is moot.

---

On the question of *dharma*-*adharma* in Draupadī's disrobing, against her will, it all comes down to this:

#### What are the rights of a slave?

Going by Yudhiṣṭhira's words, a slave has absolutely no rights:

> **If won over, until the time of destruction, I will do whatever deed I am asked to do.**

---

If on the other hand, you agree with these conclusions from G. H. Bhatt's paper, [The Draupadīvastraharaṇa Episode: An Interpolation in the Mahābhārata](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.76405#page/n17/mode/2up), your whole question is based on an event that did not take place:

> ...
>
> 7. There is another evidence in the Udyoga Parvan of the Mbh. (Critical ed.) showing that the Draupadīvastraharaṇa (Dv) episode is a late interpolation.
>      At the instance of Dhṛtarāṣṭra, Sañjaya approaches the Pāṇḍavas and
>      dissuades them from fighting, on  philosophical grounds. **Kṛṣṇa is
>      annoyed at the sermon of Sañjaya** and **draws his attention to the
>      atrocities committed by the Kauravas**. There is a bare reference to
>      Duḥśāsana bringing Draupadī to the hall but **there is no mention of Dv.**
>      and **catching hold of her hair in Kṛṣṇa's retort to Sañjaya**. Later on,
>      Yudhiṣṭhira, also, rebukes Sañjaya and enumerates all heinous offences
>      perpetrated by the Kauravas. Here also, as before, there is no
>      reference to Dv., but there is an allusion to Duḥśāsana's seizing
>      Draupadī's hair only. These are the two occasions where Kṛṣṇa and
>      Yudhiṣṭhira are expected to make a reference to the Dv., if it were a
>      fact at all. The omission of the Dv. event is most significant, and is
>      quite sufficient to prove that the Dv. episode was not part of the
>      original Mbh.
> 8. Further, the Karṇa Parvan of the Mbh. (Citraśālā Press ed.) furnishes us with additional evidence. During fighting, the wheel of
>      Karṇa's chariot sinks in the mud, and Karṇa requests Arjuna not to
>      commence fight, on the ground of military code (Ch. 90). At that time
>      **Kṛṣṇa criticises Karṇa** (Ch. 91) for his hypocrisy, and reminding him
>      of his immoral conduct in the past refers to Duḥśāsana's bringing
>      Draupadī to the assembly-hall, **but does not mention the removal of
>      Draupadī's garment**, and **even the seizure of her hair**. Had the Dv. been
>      a fact, a reference to it on such an occasion was necessary, nay,
>      inevitable. Kṛṣṇa's silence on this point is, by itself, an adequate
>      piece of evidence in support of the interpolated nature of the Dv.
>      episode.
> 9. The same Parvan, again, furnishes another evidence also. In the Ch. 83, there is a dialogue between Bhīma and Duḥśāsana, before Bhīma
>      fulfills his vow of drinking the blood of Duḥśāsana. In two places,
>      Bhīma refers to Duḥśāsana dragging the hair of Draupadī, but is
>      wonderfully silent on the removal of her garment. Duḥśāsana in reply
>      to Bhīma refers in a boasting manner to his act of dragging Draupadī's
>      hair, but not to that of stripping her of her clothes. **If Draupadī's
>      garment was actually removed by Duḥśāsana, it is most unnatural for
>      both Bhīma and Duḥśāsana not to refer to it in the circumstances.** The
>      silence on the part of excited Bhīma and arrogant Duḥśāsana, regarding
>      the Dv. episode, naturally leads one to believe that there was nothing
>      of the type in the original Mbh. The episode of Bhīma drinking the
>      blood of Duḥśāsana is, as shown before, a later development; and even
>      this later interpolation does not refer to the Dv.—a feature which
>      naturally raises suspicion about the authenticity of the Dv. episode.
>
> ...
>
> 12. Besides the internal evidence, there is also some external evidence in support of our theory. **The Bhāgavata Purāṇa** (Bh) is
>       clearly a work glorifying Kṛṣṇa as the highest divinity, the lord of
>       Vraja and dear to Gopīs. There are in the Bh. altogether four
>       references to the actions of Duḥśāsana which mention only the seizure
>       of Draupadī's hair and are **wonderfully silent on the Dv.** It has been
>       shown that the Dv. episode was developed with Draupadī's fervent
>       appeal to Kṛṣṇa, the lord of Vraja and dear to Gopīs, with the purpose
>       of magnifying the personality of Kṛṣṇa. One would naturally expect the
>       Bh., a work purely Kṛṣṇaite in nature, to refer to the Dv. episode
>       with an appeal to Kṛṣṇa. But the omission from the Bh. is most
>       significant, and shows that the Dv. episode did not appear in the
>       original Mbh.
>
> ...
>
> 17. The last point for consideration is the society in the times of the Pāṇḍavas and the Kauravas. The only evidence that is available is
>       literary, and that too is scanty. In the Rāmāyaṇa, Rāvaṇa kidnapped
>       Sītā but did not make any attempt to outrage her modesty during her
>       stay in Laṅkā and this shows some culture even on the part of
>       Rāvaṇa, the villain of the sister epic. The literature ranging from
>       the Brāhmans to the Śūdras does not show the moral deterioration
>       which could have made the conduct such as that of Duḥśāsana quite
>       normal. It appears that the society of the Pāṇḍava-Kaurava period was
>       not so depraved as to make Duḥśāsana's action possible. At any rate
>       the moral standard of the Kṣatriyas at the time of the Bhārata battle
>       was far from being low. And this would not leave any scope for the
>       most abominable action of removing the garment of Draupadī by
>       Duḥśāsana in the original epic, which was in all probability a work of
>       pure history.
> 18. **The examination of the whole evidence available in connection with the Dv. episode, thus, leads us to the irresistible conclusion that
>       the Dv. episode did not form part of the original epic and that it was
>       introduced later on by the redactors of the epic**, with motives too
>       well-known. A careful study of the critical edition of the Mbh. and
>       the most valuable foot-notes and the appendices therein, make it
>       possible to find out the several stages in the development of the Dv.
>       episode.

Comment: Do you actually believe that a wife is husband's property or is it just for the answer?

Comment: No, I don't. To answer these questions you have to imagine yourself as being present during Ramayana-Mahabharata times. Put yourself in their shoes, during those situations, etc. @Random-15

Comment: Clearly it was dharma. So Duryodhana was not wrong here.

Comment: @Vikas Stripping off a woman is clearly adharma let it be now or in the past. Check the morality. Duryodhana was wrong here. Draupadi is not only a woman, she is the queen at that time.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Why don't you write a separate answer and present your views with some references? 'she is the queen at that time' - Isn't Draupadi a queen due to the fact that Yudhiṣṭhira is a king? If king is now a slave, what is the status of the queen – this is the question!

Comment: @Sarvabhouma she was theoretically daasi not queen. Doesn't matter what Vidur said or not. Whatever happened, just happened.

Answer (score 1):

On [command](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01107.htm) of Ambika/Ambalika their daasi visited Vyasa and Vidura born.

Dhritrastra had a son named Yuyutsu from a [daasi during Gandhari's pregnancy](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01116.htm).

But, such things were not agreed by all daasis. For example, Keechaka [asked](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m04/m04015.htm) Shairandhri for the same which she refused. When he forced to do so Shairandhri's husband Vallabh killed him.

---

In specific case of Draupadi and Duryodhana, it has to be understood that she never became daasi at all, so no such question arises.

In views of **Vidura**:

> Ye Kauravas, take to your heart this high precept that I declare. If virtue is persecuted, the whole assembly becometh polluted. **If Yudhishthira had staked her before he was himself won, he would certainly have been regarded as her master. If, however a person staketh anything at a time when he himself is incapable of holding any wealth, to win it is very like obtaining wealth in a dream**. 
>   ~[Sabha Parva: SECTION LXX](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02070.htm)

Comment: whatever Vidur said. But result was such that Yuddhisthir lost Draupadi. Now how can one argue that she was not daasi? In recent Cricket World cup, too many things went against New Zealand. But England won. Now how can you say England didn't win?

Comment: @Vikas how can someone loose something when don't possess that...

Comment: I think your comment is in right direction. But I want to explore it a bit, so I can better understand. Would you please edit your answer and further explain what you just wrote above? Will be really helpful.

Comment: @Vikas it's there in answer.. " If Yudhishthira had staked her before he was himself won, he would certainly have been regarded as her master.".. as Yudhisthira staked Pandavas before he was won so they became daasa and later were freed by Dhritrastra as a boon to Draupadi...but as he staked Draupadi after he was himself won so Draupadi didn't become daasi..you can check Arjuna's statement too in this regard in the link given in answer..

Comment: in simple words, does it mean I can't bet you in any game because neither I know you, nor I have any right on you?

Comment: Whatever you have written doesn't clarify it. Please edit as suggested so I can accept it.

Answer (score -1):

It was not Duryodhana, who said this.

It was [Karna, who said as follows](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02067.htm), to Vikarna, who objected to Draupadi being ill-treated:

> O son of the Kuru race, the gods have ordained only one husband for one woman. This Draupadi, however, hath many husbands. **Therefore, certain it is that she is an unchaste woman.** To bring her, therefore, into this assembly attired though she be in one piece of cloth--**even to uncover her is not at all an act that may cause surprise.**
>
> Whatever wealth the Pandavas had--she herself and these Pandavas themselves,--have all been justly won by the son of Suvala. O Dussasana, this Vikarna speaking words of (apparent) wisdom is but a boy. **Take off the robes of the Pandavaas also the attire of Draupadi.**

Coming to the aspect of Dharma, it is very subtle.  What Duryodhana and Karna thought to be Dharma, was not accepted by Pandavas and Draupadi.  That was why great war occurred.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: No one can tell which is Dharma, to the satisfaction of all. What one can thought to be Dharma, may not be accepted by others. Ravana thought it is dharma to Rakshasas to abduct women of their wish but Sri Rama thought it is his dharma to protect his wife. Debate never ends @Vikas

Comment: So why Krishna favored Pandavas only? He must have thought stripping Draupadi was adharma.

Comment: I had already answered in your other question.  Krishna said at the end of the war to Balarama - The Pandavas of unsullied prowess are our natural friends. They are the children of our own sire's sister!@Vikas

Comment: I didn't get it.

Comment: @Vikas: **Sire** means a respectful form of address for someone of high social status, especially a king. Krishna's father and Pandavas's mother Kunti were born to same Shurasena.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunti#Birth_and_early_life).  So Kunti was Krishna's paternal aunt.  So there was blood relation between Pandavas and Krishna.