# Is there any mention of Adhika Masa in Mahabharata War?

Tags: history, itihasa, mahabharata

The online debate for dating Mahabharata is going strong between 3067 BCE and 5561 BCE groups on Twitter and [YouTube](https://youtu.be/Y2dm24eIYC0).

Both these years conjecture that there was  an Adhika Masa during the year of Mahabharata War.

---

**But are there any explicit mentions of Adhika masa during Mahabharata War or any  mentions of how Adhika Masa is calculated to exist or not in a particular year, in entire Mahabharata literature?**

Comment: "any mentions of Adhika Masa in entire Mahabharata literature" -- yes ("there is an increase of two months in every five years" ~  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35796/12304 )...

Comment: @YDS there Bhishma mentions that they were Adhika Masas. But my question is was therr an Adhika Masa during the war. Is it explicitly mentioned anywhere? During the war or is there a method to calculate when Ashika Masa occurs?

Comment: @YDS I have edited the question to make it more clear. Please consider writing an Answer. Also YDS when do you think the war happend?

Comment: most of panchangas say that it's 5122th Year of Kaliyuga so near 3k BCE looks more relevant..i don't hv much knowledge of astronomy, can't comment on astronomical calculations.. @MrGreenGold